# How to explicitly increment and return the value of a identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I have to get the next ID of an `identity` column, set it to other table and return.

That's how I thought it can be done:

```
declare @NeededID as bigint

select @NeededID = IDENT_INCR('Table1')

update Table2 
set NeededID = @NeededID 
where ID = @SomeID

return @NeededID
```

But when I try this, the `@NeededID` is always the same, and I would like it to be incremented.

Been more specific, I want to get the nextval (Oracle) of an `Identity` column of a table.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why? You shouldn't ever do this. It's not concurrency-safe, and the implementation of identity is not giving you any guarantees. You should never rely on other behaviours of identity than the fact that the number is guaranteed to be unique - *after* it has been inserted and committed. Everything else is dangerous. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? You're probably approaching it completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this, but you do not answer anything. I don't want to know if is a good approaching or not.

Comment: That's why this is a comment, not an answer. `IDENT_INCR` returns the increment, not the incremented value. You're trying to fit some Oracle patern on MS SQL, and that's not going to end well. Which is why I asked you *why* you're trying to do this. There has to be a better way.

Comment: One word: **you CANNOT do this**. Period. An `identity` value is only ever **defined** at the time the actual insert **happens**. You **CANNOT** detect / determine the value ahead of time. If you need that ability, use a `SEQUENCE` (new in SQL Server **2012**) instead

Comment: Also read: [Bad habits to kick : making assumptions about IDENTITY](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity)

Comment: @marc_s: I'm sorry, but instead of going on a rant about how bad it is, that someone wants to know the value of an identity ahead of time, wouldn't it be better to point their attention to some of the SQL Server features that lets you get around this problem in an elegant way? For example the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Comment: @marc_s I've seen this before ask heere. I don't want to have another row in my table1, i just want to get the next id of the identity column and not let anyone use it, in other words, the table1 column will never use this ID.

Comment: @Dan: I pointed the oP to the obvious solution for SQL Server 2012 - the `SEQUENCE` ....

Comment: I think sequece can be an option, but it's not the best option for me at this moment, but thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry - the comment was hidden on my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since you're finally starting to give us some of the tasks you're actually trying to accomplish, why not try this:

1. Insert a new row into `Table1`
2. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the ID and insert that into `Table2`
3. Delete the row from `Table1`

You've got your gap, and you've got the proper identity value.

Comment: Hahahaha this is probably the most absurd thing i've ever seen in my life, but I do think it will work. Hahaha thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
Declare @NextID BigInt
Select @NextID = IsNull(Max(ID), 1) + 1
       From Your_Table
```

The ablove query work only everything is fine.
The best option will be:

```
DBCC CheckIdent('Table_name')
```

Comment: Sorry, but is is ***NOT*** reliable, nor accurate. This *might* be correct 80% of the time - but definitely ***NOT*** 100% of the time! This is **really bad advice** - read: [Bad habits to kick : making assumptions about IDENTITY](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity) - we ***CANNOT*** under any circumstances make reliable predictions for the next value of an `IDENTITY` column. Period.

Comment: Read the link I posted - even `CHECKIDENT` isn't foolproof - you just ***CANNOT*** determine an `IDENTITY` value ahead of time - get used to it! That's just the way it is. Stop trying and accept the fact.

Comment: This works fine, but i do need that the next insert on the table1 do not accept the ID inserted on table2 NeededId value.